# Why does it say unhashable type: 'list' even though it is a string?

Tags: python

```
game_locs = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
ZONENAME = ['Town Market', 'Town Entrance', 'Town Square', 'Town Hall', "", 'Home', "", "", ""]
DESCRIPTION = 'description'
EXAMINATION = 'examine'
SOLVED = False
UP = 'up', 'north'
DOWN = 'down', 'south'
LEFT = 'left', 'west'
RIGHT = 'right', 'east'

zonemap = {}
for i in range(len(game_locs)):
    x = game_locs[i]
    if x[0] == 'a':
        if x[1] == '1':
            zonemap.update({'a1': {
                ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
                DESCRIPTION: "description",
                EXAMINATION: "examine",
                SOLVED: False,
                UP: "You cannot move up from here",
                DOWN: game_locs[i + 4],
                LEFT: "You cannot move left from here",
                RIGHT: game_locs[i + 1]
            }})
        elif x[1] == '4':
            zonemap.update({'a4': {
                ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
                DESCRIPTION: "description",
                EXAMINATION: "examine",
                SOLVED: False,
                UP: "You cannot move up from here",
                DOWN: game_locs[i + 4],
                LEFT: game_locs[i - 1],
                RIGHT: "You cannot move right from here"}
            })
        else:
            zonemap.update({f'a{indx}': {
                ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
                DESCRIPTION: "description",
                EXAMINATION: "examine",
                SOLVED: False,
                UP: "You cannot move up from here",
                DOWN: game_locs[i + 4],
                LEFT: game_locs[i - 1],
                RIGHT: game_locs[i + 1]}
            })
    elif x[0] == 'b':
        if x[1] == '1':
            zonemap.update({'b1': {
                ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
                DESCRIPTION: "description",
                EXAMINATION: "examine",
                SOLVED: False,
                UP: game_locs[i - 4],
                DOWN: game_locs[i + 4],
                LEFT: "You cannot move left from here",
                RIGHT: game_locs[i + 1]}
            })
        elif x[1] == '4':
            zonemap.update({'b4': {
                ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
                DESCRIPTION: "description",
                EXAMINATION: "examine",
                SOLVED: False,
                UP: game_locs[i - 4],
                DOWN: game_locs[i + 4],
                LEFT: game_locs[i - 1],
                RIGHT: "You cannot move right from here"}
            })
        else:
            zonemap.update({f'b{indx}': {
                ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
                DESCRIPTION: "description",
                EXAMINATION: "examine",
                SOLVED: False,
                UP: game_locs[i - 4],
                DOWN: game_locs[i + 4],
                LEFT: game_locs[i - 1],
                RIGHT: game_locs[i + 1]}
            })
```

but I receive the error

```
    zonemap.update({'a1': {
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

what would be the reason for this? 'a1' is clearly a string and the key is a dictionary and not a list, so what would be the reason I am getting this error? I am using PyCharm to test the code and using Python 3.8. A dictionary is definitely hashable right?  So I don't understand why this is happening.  Context: txt-based RPG game

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ZONENAME = ['Town Market', 'Town Entrance', 'Town Square', 'Town Hall', "", 'Home', "", "", ""]
> ```
>
> ```
> zonemap.update({'a1': {
>     ZONENAME: ZONENAME[i],
>     ...
> })
> ```

The error gives the approximate location of the error, but since it's a multi-line statement the error is actually on the following line in the nested dict. `ZONENAME` is a list and lists can't be used as keys.

To fix this don't use the constants as keys. Use their *names* as keys: quote the names.

```
zonemap.update({'a1': {
    'ZONENAME': ZONENAME[i],
    'DESCRIPTION': "description",
    'EXAMINATION': "examine",
    'SOLVED': False,
    'UP': "You cannot move up from here",
    'DOWN': game_locs[i + 4],
    'LEFT': "You cannot move left from here",
    'RIGHT': game_locs[i + 1]
}})
```